# Syncing files (code) on a local machine with a remote server

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, synchronization, dropbox

Almost all the code I write is usually run on a high-performance server.  Lately I've been just remotely coding via NoMachine NX (similar to VNC) remote desktop and the latency in scrolling through code and typing has become unbearable.

Is there any suggestions on how I can setup a folder locally which syncs with the high-performance server every time I save a file?  Something similar to Dropbox but I can apply to any folder.

Needs to work with Mac OS X and Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there a reason file sharing won't work for you? If the files exist on the high-performance server in a directory that you share via SMB/NFS/AFP, you can mount that share on your laptop and have a folder that's almost exactly what you want, isn't it? If you can't do that, you can set up sshfs without needing any fancy permissions, or a LAN/VPN.

Comment: Another alternative: If you use emacs, look into TRAMP, which lets you transparently edit files from a remote machine (over scp, rsh, ftp, or whatever) by copying them to a local cache and then copying them back when you save.

Answer (score 0):

> syncs with the high-performance server every time I save a file

You don't want this. What you should do instead is use a DVCS on both sides, and then push the changes to the server once they've been tested. A makefile can help with the actual push action (among others).

Comment: I already use Git for version control, but I need something to easily run quick tests of pieces of code.  It's not economical for me to push and pull for the smallest changes in my code.

The high-perf server is not a production machine, it's purely for testing and development.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the remote drive on your local machine.

If your working machine is osx and you don't feel confident with the terminal then http://panic.com/transmit/ might be a good solution.